# executing django model query?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In django model query, i want to know the sequential execution of it. Consider a query `Blog.objects.get(name='palm')`.
In this where the `Blog` is defined, is that same as class `blog` in models.py?
What is objects i can't find anything related to this in source files of django. If `Blog` is a class, then what is the type of `objects`?

I want a development side concept. Can any one please explain how django makes these possible?

Answer (score 2):

Every *non-abstract* Django model class has an attribute [**`objects`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.objects) attached to it (unless you of course explicitly remove it).

`object` is a [**`Manager`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager). It is an object that has a lot of methods to construct queries that are then send to the database to fetch/store data.

So you first access the `objects` manager of the `Blog` class, next you call `.get(name='palm')` on it. This means that Django will translate this into a query. This depends on the database system you use. For instance if it is MySQL it will look like:

```
SELECT name, some, other columns
FROM app_blog
WHERE name = 'palm'
```

The database will respond with zero, one or more rows, and Django will, in case no or more than one row is found, raise a `DoesNotExists` or `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. Otherwise it will load the data into a `Blog` object (by deserializing the columns into Python objects).

Comment: Yes i understand it. This is not the answer i was looking for. I want to know the designing concept. In python there is no Manager, right? Manager will be a python class or something? If it is `objects` means the object of `Manager`, is in't it?

Comment: How django assign objects attribute to class model.? What type of attribute, it is?, whether it is class instance of some other class?

Comment: @mcvishnu: yes if you click on the link, you see documentation about the `Manager` object.

And in Python you can assign attributes to classes. By inheritance or meta-class programming. Note that although Python supports OO programming, it is not an OO programming language: it is not a requirement.